# React div style

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to styling, sorry if this is too basic.

In my React app, I am trying to import an image from file, like so:

```
import cup from './img/cup.png'
```

and style it alongside text and everything else contained in the `<div>` like so:

```
<div style={{display:'inline-block', 
             textDecoration:'underline', 
             cursor:'pointer'}}>
  <img src={cup} alt=''/>
  <h1 className="title is-4">"Item"</h1>
</div>
```

But this works badly. Image display is too big.

I would like to reference image right into `style` and manage 'height' and 'width' (or 'size') within it as well, but haven't found a way.

is this possible? how so?

Comment: What you exact mean refer the image right into style?

Comment: refer as in `src={img}`

Comment: Do you think using style like what you have done for the outer div is a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want in vertical

```
       <div>
          <div style={{ display: "inline-block",
              textDecoration: "underline",cursor: "pointer"}}>
            <img
              style={{ height: 100 }} src={
                "https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/intro-video-poster@2x.jpg"
              } alt=""
            />
            <h1 className="title is-4">"Item"</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and if you want in horizontal

```
      <div>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", textDecoration: "underline", cursor: "pointer"}}>
            <img style={{ height: 100 }} src={
                "https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/intro-video-poster@2x.jpg"
              } alt=""
            />
            <h1 className="title is-4">"Item"</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the horizontal/vertical option for display. very useful.

Answer (score 0):

just add height and width size to your image, like this

```
  <img src={cup} alt='' height={50} width={50} />
```

also, you can add auto to and  set the size to another it will work best

```
  <img src={cup} alt='' height={50} width='auto' />
```

```html
  <img src={cup} alt='' height='auto' width={50} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the first step of you is to learn what a selector is. In short, it is a naming convention to link style with the HTML tag(s)(or dom, whatever). For example,  let's say you put a class to the image.

```
<div>
  <img src={cup} alt='' className="my-image"/>
  <h1 className="title is-4">"Item"</h1>
</div>
```

And a CSS file, which you have to import it as a dependency of the component at the header of source file, next to the **import cup from './img/cup.png'**.

style.css

```
img.my-image {
  // css rules here
}
```

Then the magic occurs, the CSS rule, e.g., the absolute/relative width/height written in the file will be applied to the image accordingly.